# Is is possible to Pipe the results of a task in F#?

Tags: f#

My code looks like this

```
let! statementData = page.EvaluateAsync("() => this.window._StatementLinesData")
let sValue = 
    JObject.Parse(statementData.Value.GetRawText()).Last.Last
    |> (fun item -> item.Children() )
    |> Seq.map(fun item -> item.ToObject<StatementLine>())
```

Is it possible to make those 2 into one statement without using .Result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I do not think it is wise to try to use `|>` at all costs. In your example, the code is clearer (I think) if you do not use it at all. It is just a sequence of bindings, extracting things from some structure and I do not think it is useful to see this as "sequence of transformations" that pipe usually represents (also, you can give the temporary variables more useful names than `item` to make the code readable):

```
let! statementData = page.EvaluateAsync("() => this.window._StatementLinesData")
let item = JObject.Parse(statementData.Value.GetRawText()).Last.Last
return item.Children() |> Seq.map(fun item -> item.ToObject<StatementLine>())
```

If you wanted to avoid `let!` and use just pipes, you need some degree of nesting. I would definitely avoid `Result` as that makes the code blocking and defeates the purpose of tasks in this case. But you could define a `map` operation to help you:

```
module Task =
  let map f (t:Task<_>) = task { 
    let! r = t
    return f r }
```

And then you can express your code using `|>` into `map` and, inside the lambda, do the extraction you need:

```
page.EvaluateAsync("() => this.window._StatementLinesData")
|> Task.map (fun statementData ->
    JObject.Parse(statementData.Value.GetRawText()).Last.Last
    |> (fun item -> item.Children() )
    |> Seq.map(fun item -> item.ToObject<StatementLine>()))
```

I think this is less readable (and also longer) than the above, but it does the same thing with lots of `|>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t immediately understand why you’d want that, but sure you can:

```
page.EvaluateAsync("() => this.window._StatementLinesData").Result
|> fun x -> JObject.Parse(x.Value.GetRawText()).Last.Last
|> fun item -> item.Children()
|> Seq.map(fun item -> item.ToObject<StatementLine>())
```

If you don’t want to use `.Result` (its a blocking operation), you can stay inside `task` or use something like `Task.map`.